# What is the Lebesgue measure of the Koch and the Minkowski curves?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, curves, fractals

Are the Koch curve and the Minkowski curve Lebesgue measurable? (I believe they are.)  If so, what are their measures? (Intuitively, it would seem to be zero.) I unfortunately can't seem to find much on this question, so I'd also be grateful for any helpful resource.

Comment: Of course, they are closed sets and, therefore, Borel.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Of course. Thanks. What about the value of the measure? Any ideas?

Comment: They have Hausdorff dimension less than two and, therefore, two dimensional measure zero.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I think I see what you mean. Thanks again. Do you know of any resource that deals with the connection between Hausdorff dimension and the Lebesgue measure? I should have been able to figure this out, but I believe I'm missing some of the basics.

Comment: Broadly speaking, imagine covering the figure as efficiently as you can with a bunch of discs of radius $r$; as you shrink $r$ toward $0$, you will obviously need more of the discs.  Hausdorff dimension tells you how the number of discs goes up as a function of the diminishing radius $r$.  Since these curves have dimension less than $2$, the number of discs must go up slower than $r^{-2}$, and this in turn means that the total area covered by them can be made arbitrarily small, so the curves must have measure $0$.

Comment: The only reference I know is [Amann and Escher's Analysis III](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783764374792) In the first chapter, they deal with general measures, in particular Hausdorff measure, Lebesgue measure. In general, for every $s>0$, we can consider the $s$-dimensional Hausdorff measure $\mathcal{H}^s$ on $\Bbb{R}^n$ (or other metric spaces). One interesting property is that if $A$ is a (for example Borel) subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$ with $\mathcal{H}^s(A)$ finite, then for every $t>s$, $\mathcal{H}^t(A) = 0$. Another fact is that $\mathcal{H}^n$ and the Lebesgue measure $\lambda^n$...

Comment: [cont.] are multiples of each other (because they are both locally finite-translation invariant measures on the Borel sigma algebra of $\Bbb{R}^n$). So, for the sets you mention, their Hausdorff dimension is $<2$. so if $d$ is the Hausdorff dimension of the set, then $\mathcal{H}^d(A)$ is finite, so $\mathcal{H}^2(A) = 0$, and hence $\lambda^2(A) = 0$. (all of these facts are there in the book either as part of the text or part of the exercises)

Comment: I also found [this set of notes](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~farbod/teaching/cornell/math6210pdf/math6210Hausdorff.pdf) online; it seems to cover most of the relevant facts.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks for these helpful comments, guys! Feel free to turn them into an answer and I'd gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that a compact set $K$ in $\mathbb R^2$ is composed of $m$ copies of itself:
$$
K = \bigcup_{i=1}^m K_i.
$$
Suppose further that each $K_i$ is geometrically similar to $K$ and scaled by the factor $r_i$. Finally, let us suppose that the intersection between any two distinct $K_i$s has Lebesgue measure zero. Then, by the additive and scaling properties of two dimensional Lebesgue measure $m$, we have
$$
m(K) = \sum_{i=1}^m m(K_i) = m(K)\sum_{i=1}^m r_i^2.
$$
Now, the only way this can happen is if either
$$
m(K) = 0 \: \: \text{ or } \: \: \sum_{i=1}^m r_i^2 = 1.
$$
In the examples given, the sets are self-similar with distinct copies intersecting in finite sets and it is easy to check directly that the summation condition is not satisfied. So we must have $m(K) = 0$.

There's an interesting connection between this and fractal dimension in that the condition
$$
\sum_{i=1}^m r_i^2 = 1
$$
implies that the fractal dimension of set should be two, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

Just repeating the comments to get this answered.

One reference is [Amann, Escher's Analysis III](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783764374792). In the first chapter, they deal with general measures, in particular Hausdorff measure and Lebesgue measure. In general, for every $s>0$, we can consider the $s$-dimensional Hausdorff measure $\mathcal{H}^s$ on $\Bbb{R}^n$ (or other metric spaces). One interesting property is that if $A$ is a (Hausdorff)-measurable subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$ (eg. every Borel set is Hausdorff and Lebesgue measurable) with $\mathcal{H}^s(A)$ finite, then for every $t>s, \mathcal{H}^t(A)=0$.

Another fact is that on $\Bbb{R}^n$ the Hausdorff $n$-measure, $\mathcal{H}^n$ and the Lebesgue measure $\lambda^n$ are multiples of each other (because they are both locally finite-translation invariant measures on the Borel/Lebesug $\sigma$-algebra of $\Bbb{R}^n$). So, for the sets you mention, their Hausdorff dimension is $<2$. Hence, $\mathcal{H}^2(A)=0$ (actually in the notes below, they show the Hausdorff dimension is $<2$ by using the fact that $\mathcal{H}^2(A) = 0$), and hence $\lambda^2(A)=0$. (all of these facts are there in the book either as part of the text or part of the exercises). [This set of online notes](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Efarbod/teaching/cornell/math6210pdf/math6210Hausdorff.pdf) also discusses these topic pretty quickly.